# a bug in simplest jQuery Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

What am I doing wrong in my jQuery widget?
I have divs on page, and call in a document.ready function:

```
  $(".codeline").comments();
```

Html containes:

```
<div class='codeline'> (some text) </div>
...
<div class='codeline'> (some text) </div>
```

And the widget:

```
jQuery.widget("rmc.comments", {

    _create: function () {

        this.element.on("click", function () { alert(1); }); // THIS DOESN'T WORK (event not fired)
        //this.element.css("color", "red"); -- THIS WORKS
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work. You are probably calling your widget before defining it. Change to:

```
$.widget("rmc.comments", {
    _create: function () {
        this.element.on("click", function () { alert(1); });
        //this.element.css("color", "red");
    }
});

$(".codeline").comments();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/10tdarhk/

Comment: Thank you, Kristoffer. That was very simple question, but I spent an hour. The solution was just to restart Chrome browser. I didn't expect that bug in Chrome. :)